# Reading utf-8 characters from a gzip file in python

Tags: python, file-io, utf-8, gzip

I am trying to read a gunzipped file (.gz) in python and am having some trouble.

I used the gzip module to read it but the file is encoded as a utf-8 text file so eventually it reads an invalid character and crashes.

Does anyone know how to read gzip files encoded as utf-8 files? I know that there's a codecs module that can help but I can't understand how to use it.

Thanks!

```
import string
import gzip
import codecs

f = gzip.open('file.gz','r')

engines = {}
line = f.readline()
while line:
    parsed = string.split(line, u'\u0001')

    #do some things...

    line = f.readline()
for en in engines:
  print(en)
```

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far?

Comment: Can you convert the utf-8 file to ascii then attempt to decompress that? hmm....

Comment: If you are getting a UnicodeDecodeError, see this related post, which shows the use of the open('errors') parameter and mentions a caveat when using the ISO-8859-1 (latin-1) encoding: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35028683/python3-unicodedecodeerror-with-readlines-method

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I don't see why this should be so hard.

What are you doing exactly?  Please explain "eventually it reads an invalid character".

It should be as simple as:

```
import gzip
fp = gzip.open('foo.gz')
contents = fp.read() # contents now has the uncompressed bytes of foo.gz
fp.close()
u_str = contents.decode('utf-8') # u_str is now a unicode string
```

---

## EDITED

This answer works for `Python2` in `Python3`, please see @SeppoEnarvi 's answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/19794943/610569 (it uses the `rt` mode for `gzip.open`.

Comment: +1 ... That is the most lucid and least complicated of the 3 answers so far.

Comment: Not necessarily the least complicated, in that you have to decode each line you read. In the getreader implementation, this happens automatically so each line is unicode

Comment: While it is a nice solution, I have a feeling that this solution won't scale well with large files.

Comment: Exactly. We want this to be interpreted correctly by the library, not by us after being required to read the whole thing into a string.

Answer (score 56):

This is possible since Python 3.3:

```
import gzip
gzip.open('file.gz', 'rt', encoding='utf-8')
```

Notice that gzip.open() requires you to explicitly specify text mode ('t').

Answer (score 21):

Maybe

```
import codecs
zf = gzip.open(fname, 'rb')
reader = codecs.getreader("utf-8")
contents = reader( zf )
for line in contents:
    pass
```

Comment: As a one-liner: for line in codecs.getreader('utf-8')(gzip.open(fname), errors='replace') which also adds control over the error handling

Answer (score 7):

The above produced tons of decoding errors. I used this:

```
for line in io.TextIOWrapper(io.BufferedReader(gzip.open(filePath)), encoding='utf8', errors='ignore'):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In pythonic form (2.5 or greater)

```
from __future__ import with_statement # for 2.5, does nothing in 2.6
from gzip import open as gzopen

with gzopen('foo.gz') as gzfile:
    for line in gzfile:
      print line.decode('utf-8')
```