# xml.etree.ElementTree and unicode findtext

Tags: python, xml, unicode, elementtree

I am trying to parse Medline xml documents using iterparse in the xml.etree.ElementTree module.  All is working well except that some of the text includes non-ascii characters.  I do not see a way of handling unicode using findtext.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried opening the file with utf8 encoding flah:

```
fd = open('some.xml', mode='r', encoding='utf-8')
xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse(fd)
```

Or use decode:

```
fd = open('some.xml', mode='r')
sio = StringIO(fd.read().decode("utf-8"))
xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse(sio)
```

Comment: I think this should work, but I'm still getting errors.  Next step is to validate that the encoding is, indeed, UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

This was a very useful post in addition to the answer above.

[Reading utf-8 characters from a gzip file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883604/reading-utf-8-characters-from-a-gzip-file-in-python)