# How to do string formatting with unicode emdash?

Tags: python, unicode, string-formatting

I am trying do string formatting with a unicode variable. For example:

```
>>> x = u"Some text—with an emdash."
>>> x
u'Some text\u2014with an emdash.'
>>> print(x)
Some text—with an emdash.
>>> s = "{}".format(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2014' in position 9: ordinal not in range(128)

>>> t = "%s" %x
>>> t
u'Some text\u2014with an emdash.'
>>> print(t)
Some text—with an emdash.
```

You can see that I have a unicode string and that it prints just fine. The trouble is when I use Python's new (and improved?) `format()` function. If I use the old style (using `%s`) everything works out fine, but when I use `{}` and the `format()` function, it fails.

Any ideas of why this is happening? I am using Python 2.7.2.

Comment: You should be very careful on Windows because if you output to console you may get an exception like this anyway.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The new `format()` is not as forgiving when you mix ASCII and unicode strings ... so try this:

```
s = u"{}".format(x)
```

Comment: Although that makes sense, that's annoying that the old `%` way takes care of it more conveniently. Explicit, implicit, yada yada, but still irritating.

Comment: Using python v3.8.2 it seems that the 'u' is not needed.

Answer (score 4):

Using the following worked well for me.  It is a variant on the other answers.

```
>>> emDash = u'\u2014'
>>> "a{0}b".format(emDash)
'a—b'
```

Answer (score 3):

The same way.

```
>>> s = u"{0}".format(x)
>>> s
u'Some text\u2014with an emdash.'
```